# Absolute element force content scroll to top

Tags: html, css

I'm using an css only responsive menu on my page. It's basicly uses checkbox with label to open and close the menu.

But i've notice when the page content scroll and I click, it's back to the top. Is there any css only solution for it?!

I'm using this tutorial as reference https://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because of the `a` tag.

when clicking `<a href="#"><a>` the browser reload the page and that is why it jumps to the top.

Change `<a>` to `<span>` and your problem should be solved.

of course, you might need to change some css to get the proper styling:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <!-- Change this to <span> instead of <a> -->
    <li class="nav-item"><span>Home</span></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm using label, changed to span and the problem persists

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, updated the answer with an example